# Assigning jQuery value in JSP/EJB

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp

I'm currently working on a small project related to shopping, and I have come across an issue. Thing is, I'm using HTML/JSP pages to display the total price of items purchased. Once I click the submit button, the value needs to go to java EJB where the value can then be stored in an SQL database. However, I am unable to proceed further. Does anyone have any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Code for JSP/HTML file

```html
<p id="sub-total">
  <strong>Total</strong>: <span id="stotal"></span>
</p>
```

Code for JSP to Bean:

```html
<h:outputLabel value="#{OrderBean.totalPrice}" id="stotal"></h:outputLabel>
```

I want to assign the value of 'stotal' to OrderBean.totalPrice. Is there a way to do that?
As of now, the value of stotal is calculated using jQuery.

Any ideas? This is important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `id` are supposed to be unique per page

Comment: $("#stotal").text ("123.45);

Comment: First of all I would say it is not a good option to do calculations in UI. We can easily hack using firebug or developer tool. Best is calculate it in server side.<br/>

Comment: Do you have "OrderBean.totalPrice" field as a form input? 
 If have,then do step 2; 
If No,then do step 1 and 2; 
step 1: Create a html hidden-field with name attribute should be "OrderBean.totalPrice" and for ID you can enter whatever. Lets say ID is x. 
step 2: Then set value to hidden field from stotal. Like bellow.
 hidden field code   <input type="hidden" name="OrderBean.totalPrice">
 
js code document.getElementById("x").value=document.getElementById("stotal").value;